# Good method for archiving MYSQL table data?

Tags: mysql, archive, archiving

I recently inherited a website and they have a simple back-end area which was created using phpmaker. The back-end displays various MYSQL database tables.

There are two tables which hold registration information related to promotions/contests the company runs online. The client wants to begin archiving the registration data monthly, but still have the data accessible for future export or review.

So, can anyone tell me what the best approach would be to achieve this? I read about partitioning and [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/), but I'm not sure which - if either - would be a smart choice.

I would prefer to keep the table names the same because the table name is referenced in several instances within the PHP code running the promo/contest applications. I would also like for everything to be 'automatic' or at least executed at the click of a button; though I realize that might not be completely realistic.

I should note that I **do not** have the phpmaker project file and have been unable to obtain it.

Any help on this matter would be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MK-Archiver](http://www.maatkit.org/) This is a good way to archive live mysql database tables

What MK- Archiver does is to archive rows from a table to another table and/or a file